# Capitalizing of Titles

Tags: capitalization

In  English, several types of words are capitalized in titles that are not normally capitalized. In German, are words capitalized in the same way? And if not, how are they capitalized?

Comment: well, regarding the Fact all Nouns are already capitalized )))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In German there are no extra rules for capitalization of titles. This means: Titles are capitalized exactly according to the same rules as any other German text.

Rules of thumb:

> 1. Standard: All words are written with lower case characters only.
> 2. Exceptions from that standard:
>      2.1. The first letter of **all nouns** is always written as an uppercase letter.
>      2.2. The first letter of **the first word in a sentence** is always written as an uppercase letter.

There are also other rules, that clarify which word takes the role of a noun in a sentence, and which one doesn't, which can be quite tricky sometimes, and of course you can also use CAPS LOCK, which means: write everything in uppercase letters only, but you can do this in titles as well as in normal texts.

I give you an example:

There was a movie with this English title:

> [image]
>   Those Magnificent Men in their Flying Machines

As you can see, all words except "in" and "their" have been capitalized. The German title of this movie is:

> [image]
>   Die tollkühnen Männer in ihren fliegenden Kisten

You can see: Only three words are capitalized:

- **Die**
  Because it is the first word
- **Männer, Kisten**
  Because they are nouns

All other words are neither nouns nor the first word, and therefore written all in lowercase letters.

Comment: To me, this seems weird, as in English, "Flying Machine" is a compound noun meaning "Aeroplane", rather than being treated as an adjective and a noun. Compound nouns cause headaches for people trying to write automatic title-case scripts for English, as it should be "The In Crowd" but "Alice in Wonderland". Is treating them as separate words a translation error, or does German not have the concept of compound nouns? Knowing nothing about German, I'd have expected Fliegendenkisten or Fleiderkisten or somesuch.

Comment: @DewiMorgan: German has lots of compound nouns. The longest ever used in an official document was the title of a law: [Grundstücksverkehrsgenehmigungszuständigkeitsübertragungsverordnung](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Grundstücksverkehrsgenehmigungszuständigkeitsübertragungsverordnung). But "flying machine" translates to "fliegende Maschine" and in the movie title *Kiste* (engl: *box*) was used as funny sounding synonym. A compound German word would be *Flugmaschine*, but *Flugmaschine* is not *"flying machine"* in English. *"Flugmaschine"*is *"flight machine"*.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! So it is a good translation, which deviates from using identical grammar, in order to far better depict the *feeling* of the English title :)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast If a title were put in title case in German like it would in English, would it look very strange to German speakers? Or is the concept generally understood? Like in your movie title example, if it were in title case, would it look like an error or just a stylization?

Comment: @DanLeveille *"would it look very strange to German speakers?"* Yes, because it is a wrong as anY oTher WroNG uSagE of upPerCasE LetterS. *"Is the concept understood?"* Yes, because a very high percentage of German native speakers also speaks English and everybody has seen Engish titles before. But it's still wrong. *"Error or stylization?"* It not only would look like an error, it is an error. And therefore nobody who speaks German writes German titles in such a manner.

Answer (score 13):

I am not aware of such extra capitalization for titles in Germany.

As far as I know, titles are capitalized like any normal sentence. Or they are ALL CAPS, of course.

Comment: All CAPS in a title is more a question of *typography* rather than *orthography* - But basically, your answer is correct. Note that punctuation is different in titles, normally, but that is the same in English.

Comment: @tofro: Correct, it is more a typographical issue, but the result is the same and then you can't judge the capitalization. Anyway, all caps are not so usual. And indeed, you don't punctuate titles the same way. You omit the final period, for instance.