# Usage of 'denn' and 'da' in a song

Tags: conjunction, conjugation

I was reading through the lyrics in 'Bringst du mich heute Nacht nach Hause' by Michelle

She sings: "Denn heute Nacht da brauch ich einen Freund"

How is Denn being used in the final verse? I'm confused because it follows shortly after with 'Da' and it doesn't sound right to have two conjunctions so close together. What would the closest translation of this be to English?

Comment: completely unrelated: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xh1y7Jkikuk :)

Comment: In German we do capitalize all nouns, but nothing else, and we do this independent from where the text appears. There is no capitalization of titles in German. This means, that the capitalization of the words *du, mich, heute* and *nach* is wrong, even if they appear within a title. I corrected this for you. See also https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/37442/capitalizing-of-titles

Answer (score 5):

She sings:

> Denn heute Nacht **,** da brauch ich einen Freund.

*Because tonight, that night I need a friend.*

Note the comma. **Heute Nacht** and **da** is a list. Split it into two sentences:

> Denn **heute Nacht** brauch ich einen Freund.
>
> Denn **da** brauch ich einen Freund.

This isn't the conjuction *da* but [the adverb *da*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/da_Adverb_dort_hier), a substitution for *heute Nacht*. In the original sentence, it emphasizes *heute Nacht*.

---

How to guess that? Because if it was the conjunction *da*, the following part of the sentence had to be a subordinate clause, using another word order pattern:

> Denn heute Nacht, da ich einen Freund **brauch**, … .

Comment: Not part of the answer, just a comment. When listening to *Schlager*, you will encounter lists with the adverb *da* as the last element very often. It's a filler used to sustain the rhythm, if the texter had no better idea. Sounds very cheesy.

Answer (score 1):

*Denn* simply means *because*.

> Denn heute Nacht brauch ich einen Freund

and

> Denn heute Nacht, da brauch ich einen Freund

mean exactly the same thing.

The adverb *da* can mean:

in this place, there, here, at that time, at that moment, under these circumstances

This is similar to the sentence

> Auf der Alm, do gibt's koa Sünd' (Auf der Alm, da gibt es keine Sünde)

In most cases, the construction with *da* is found in lyrical texts (poems, song texts and the like) to stay in the rhythm.