# Upper or lowercase following an equals sign "="?

Tags: punctuation, capitalization

I am aware of the rules regarding "Doppelpunkt" but I am not sure how exactly this applies to capitalization after

=

instead of

:

An example:

> "Mehr Glück" = "Mehr Spaß!"

Or

> "Mehr Glück = "mehr Spaß!

You could replace the example string with any full sentence, but I am still not sure how I would treat it.

Comment: There's no strict rule for _=_ that I am aware of, since _=_ isn't a regular punctuation character. I'd prefer _"Mehr Glück" = "Mehr Spaß!"_ though.

Comment: Thank you, I would agree with your preference, since this is for localization purposes I will add this as my recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

If your read this sentence it becomes:

> Mehr Glück ist mehr Spaß.

So, here the equal sign clearly stands for the verb of the sentence and it is not any kind of punctuation. It is just some kind of abbreviation. And this again means: No capitalization.

Btw: It is not recommended to replace words in written texts by any special characters. So technically this:

> Mehr Glück = mehr Spaß.

is wrong. But of course it will be understood, so in some informal types of text it is acceptable. But in those types of text where it is acceptable (like postings in social media) nobody really cares about correct capitalization.

Comment: Is this a proof for "no special character" or just a typo for "with": `in written texts my any special characters.`?

Comment: It is for informal text but I would still like to guarantee some resemblance of grammar. 
The lower case one just looked very awkward to me so I was pushing for capitalizing. I was mostly wondering if there was any hard rule that makes lower case the "only correct" choice.

Comment: @KataWoo: Die Regel ist, dass "mehr" kein Hauptwort ist, das aus sich selbst groß geschrieben wird und dass es nicht das erste Wort des Satzes ist. Eine graphische Ähnlichkeit von : und = kommt nicht in Betracht. "Mehr Glück gleich mehr Spaß." noch als Alternative genannt, zu "ist".

Comment: @KataWoo: Also read this: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/37442/capitalizing-of-titles